# Windows Phone 7: Build a music alarm clock?

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, windows-phone, mpns

I'd like to create an app for the Windows Phone 7 that plays a song at a user-specified time. My idea was to use push notifications to trigger the app to play some content on the device. However, I'm not sure if this is possible. To quote [MSDN about raw notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941124%28v=VS.92%29.aspx):

> If you do not wish to update the Tile
>   or send a toast notification, you can
>   instead send raw information to your
>   application using a raw notification.
>   If your application is not currently
>   running, the raw notification is
>   discarded on the Microsoft Push
>   Notification Service and is not
>   delivered to the device. The payload
>   of a raw notification has a maximum
>   size of 1 KB.

Looks like this won't work. Is there another way to implement this? I know that wp7 doesn't have multitasking, so I can't have the app running in the background at all times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way for timed (or other background) notifications of your program on the current (first) version of Windows Phone 7.
I needed something similar. After finding nothing I asked MS support, and they told me this is impossible to achieve in WP7 right now.

Seems the only way is to wait for an update for WP7 :(

Comment: Yes. To be able to do this you'd need to have the process run in the background until the desired time and then wake up or have something trigger the app at the desired time. This could be a trigger from something else on the device or from an external service.  AS you state though, none of these options are currently available.